# Determine a function from a monotone condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f\in C^\infty((0,1),\mathbb{R}_+)\cap C_0([0,1])$ and $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}f'(t)=+\infty,\lim_{t\to1^-}f'(t)=-\infty.$$
Furthermore, if $$F(t):=\frac{f''(t)}{f(t)(1+(f'(t))^2)^2}$$
is monotoinc in $(0,1)$, find $f$.

The function $\sqrt{x-x^2}$ is obviously a solution. And $F$ is a constant at that time. But I am unable to determine whether it is the unique function that satisfies the conditions. The condition "monotonic" seems too weak for me.

My attempts: The numerator of $F'$ is $$-f'f''(1+(f')^2+4ff'')+ff'''(1+(f')^2).$$ And we can suppose $F'\geq0$ since otherwise we can change $f(t)$ to $f(1-t)$. I tried to analyze the behavior of $F'$ at the maximum point of $f$ and use the comparation theorems in ODE, but I didn't success, and I still don't know how to use the conditions of $f'$.

I also tried to let $g=f^2$ and wanted to show $g'''=0$, but it didn't work as well.

Any suggestion or counter-example will be appreciated.

EDIT: I heard that $F$ is actually the Gaussian curvature of the rotational surface of $f$ about the $t$-axis. And the conditions of $f'$ promises the surface to be $C^1$. Will this help?